# Creating a new page template

Tags: page-template

### Problem

I have a template and I want to add new page to my theme for example about. I rename file to `template-about.php`. Also added comments into template:

```
<? /*Template Name: About Us*/?>
```

However, in admin panel do not showing this page. I've read the Theme Handbook on [Page Templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/)

Comment: Do you have *short* PHP tags enabled? Try e.g. `<?php` instead of `<?`

Comment: Works when I test it. Do you have PHP short tags enabled? Even if you do, don't use them. Use `<?php`

Comment: PHP shorttags are really really bad coding practice in my opinion. It is the lazyman coding way. IMHO, php shorttags should never have made it into php. Not all servers have shorttags enables, which if it is the case in your case, php shorttags will throw a fatal error (*WSOD*)

Comment: I'm not for short tags, Peter, but I'm not against laziness, either. A lazy monkey took a stick one day and hit the banana with it, instead of climbing the tree...

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu being lazy is not bad if you are cleverly lazy, but using bad methods to be lazy is. A lazy monkey took a pee one day in the kitchen sink because the toilet was too far and he was too lazy to take the walk to the toilet. He came to the conclusion that whenever the kitchen is nearer, he can use the kitchen sink as a tiolet to pee in. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template name: About Us
 */
```

WordPress could be finicky about the short tags (`<?` vs `<?php`) and comment formatting - shouldn't be, but better safe than sorry. Also, make sure that you have the Screen Option to display Page Attributes turned on and that you're on Add New **Page**, not Post:

[image: image showing Page Attributes]